# System.InvalidCastException in C# console

Tags: c#

When I Execute the following code, I get an error saying.

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.ValueField(Object value)
   at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field[T](DataRow row, String columnName)
   at ProbabilityFunctions.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\....:line 38Press any key to continue . . .
```

What I am trying to do in this code is, I am retrieving data from a table and storing it into another table. I am passing this table as an argument into a classifier to undergo further operation. Please tell me the error. Datatypes of height,uname are varchar... others are int...

```
using System;
    using System.Data;
    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

    namespace ProbabilityFunctions
    {
        public class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                try
                {
                    String con = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=sample;UID=root;password=password";
                    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(con);
                    String s = "select * from cart";
                    MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                    MySqlCommand cmd2 = conn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd2.CommandText = "select count(*) from cart";
                    conn.Open();
                    int z = Convert.ToInt32(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());

                    conn.Close();
                    MySqlDataAdapter dat = new MySqlDataAdapter(s, conn);
                    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

                    dat.Fill(tbl);
                    cmd.CommandText = s;
                    DataTable table = new DataTable();
                    table.Columns.Add("name");
                    table.Columns.Add("Height", typeof(double));
                    table.Columns.Add("cost", typeof(double));
                    table.Columns.Add("FootSize", typeof(double));


                    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
                    {
                        DataRow row = tbl.Rows[i];
                        Double height = row.Field<Double>("height");
                        Double fsize = row.Field<Double>("fsize");
                        Double cost = row.Field<Double>("cost");
                        String uname = row.Field<String>("uname");
                        table.Rows.Add(uname, height, cost, fsize);
                    }


                    Classifier classifier = new Classifier();
                    classifier.TrainClassifier(table);

                    Console.WriteLine(classifier.Classify(new double[] { 4, 150, 12 }));
                    Console.Read();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Write(ex.ToString());
                }
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What line do you get the error?

Comment: Please tell _us_ the error.  What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Don't call `conn.Close();` before code that uses `conn`. That's definitely going to cause problems.

Comment: Check to see if int z = Convert.ToInt32(cmd2.ExecuteScalar()) return an array not just only one value.

Comment: @lauCosma `Convert.ToInt32` only throws a `FormatException` or `OverflowException`, not an `InvalidCastException`. Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @lauCosma Execute scalar will return single value not an array AFAIK.

Comment: What is the datatype of `height` `fsize` etc in Table?

Comment: updated datatypes in description

Comment: If Height is a `varchar`, it can't directly be cast as a `double`; you'll need to assign it to a `string` and use `double.Parse()` or `double.TryParse()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely happening on one of these lines:

```
Double height = row.Field<Double>("height");
Double fsize = row.Field<Double>("fsize");
Double cost = row.Field<Double>("cost");
```

You will receive this exception if the underlying field type can not be cast to a double directly.  From the [documentation for `Field<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), InvalidCastException is thrown when:

> The value type of the underlying column could not be cast to the type specified by the generic parameter, T.

Given the stack trace, it appears your "height" column within the underlying table is not actually numeric, and can't be cast to a double.  If it's stored as a string in the input dataset, for example, you'll have to extract a string and convert to a double afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Now it is clear. You cannot unbox a boxed `int` to `double` or any other type. Only possible types allowed are `int` and `Nullable<int>`.

Get Field as int and convert it to double then, It should work

```
double height = (double)row.Field<int>("height");
```